# I can't make the beat extend on big band in skullgirls?

Tags: skullgirls

[image]

I am kinda new to this game and I don't understand how I can pull out this on big band. I don't understand the beginning: should the first move be right, diagonal, and right or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a so called [Shoryuken input](https://streetfighter.fandom.com/wiki/Inputs#.27Complex.27_Inputs), or a `623` (look at your numpad).

It's a bit tricky to pull off, especially for someone new. You basically want to do a movement that goes towards, down, and down-towards. I think Skullgirls is leanient with this and you can move the stick towards, down *through down-towards*, and back to down-towards.

Hit Punch just as you reach the down-towards position.